# Проблема с Url'ами в Ajax-навигации

Tags: ajax

Проблема такая.

Используем следующий плагин для Ajax-навигации:
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

В идеале нужно такое поведение:
**http://site.ru/article/12**
=>
**http://site.ru/#!/article/12**

Чтобы последнюю ссылку можно было вставить в браузер и получить тот же контент, что и для первой.

Сейчас при заходе на страничку
**http://site.ru/article/12**
и кликая на другую статью адрес становится примерно таким:
**http://site.ru/article/12#/article/14**

Т.е. baseURL становится не именем хоста, а адресом неаяксовой ссылки, по которой перешли.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, видимо, слэш забыли при указывании ссылки в `href`, если я правильно понял.

По идее, у вас должен быть какой либо `listener`, который будет слушать ваш `url`, и знак хэша должен стоять сразу-же после `site.ru/`. То есть ссылки должны быть вида `/#!/article/12` (начинаться со слэша).